# Load to 256 bit AVX2 register from an array with 0 padding

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx2

I want to load 4 doubles into a 256 bit register and pad with 0's if the array size is less than 4.

```
register __m256d c = _mm256_loadu_pd(C);
```

Now suppose C had just three elements in it, I want to pad the last "entry" in register c to 0. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: There's always [`vmaskmovpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov) which can even do fault-suppression if that last element happens to be in an unmapped page.  Do you need that?  See also [Intel store instructions on delibrately overlapping memory regions](//stackoverflow.com/q/59581140) for some info about efficiency of vmaskmov (mostly for stores, but it is efficient for loads on AMD, unlike for stores).

Comment: @PeterCordes that would require me to specify a mask.. looking for a simpler option

Comment: Yes, you'd need a mask, which you could get from a load from a sliding window onto an array of `-1, -1, -1, 0,0,0`.  [Vectorizing with unaligned buffers: using VMASKMOVPS: generating a mask from a misalignment count? Or not using that insn at all](//stackoverflow.com/q/34306933).  Or you could maybe generate it on the fly from the length, like `(1ULL<<(n*8)) - 1` and vmovd to an XMM + `vpmovsxbq ymm, xmm`.  You don't have a lot of good options, unfortunately, especially if you can't pad the source data to guarantee that it's at least save to load 32 bytes from the pointer `C`.

Comment: Until AVX512 makes masking a first-class operation (and probably even then), you're definitely going to want to peel out handling the tail of a big array, or the whole small array, separate from your main loop.  For tail handling in larger arrays, it can work to do a load that ends at the last element (potentially overlapping with earlier loads if the array size isn't a multiple of the vector width).  For vertical SIMD copying into a dst array you can just let the store overlap, but for a horizontal sum or something yeah you need to avoid double-counting the overlap so this way doesn't work.

Comment: If you know at compile-time that you have exactly 3 elements, you can combine a `VMOVSD` (loading the third element) with a `VPERM2F128` (permuting the third element to the third position while loading the first two elements).

Comment: Correction: `VPERM2F128` takes a 256bit memory operand, so you'll actually need a separate 128 bit load. And in that case you can also do `VINSERTF128` to combine both halves. This is what `_mm256_set[r]_m128d` will generate for you: https://godbolt.org/z/yifEK_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one method. Unlike `_mm256_maskload_pd`, the function below doesn’t need to load or create the mask.

```
// Load 3 doubles from memory, zero out the 4-th one.
inline __m256d load3( const double* source )
{
    const __m128d low = _mm_loadu_pd( source );
    const __m128d high = _mm_load_sd( source + 2 );
    return _mm256_set_m128d( high, low );   // vinsertf128
}
```

For completeness, here’s 2 other variants.

```
// Zero out the high 2 double lanes.
inline __m256d zeroupper( __m128d low2 )
{
    const __m256d low = _mm256_castpd128_pd256( low2 ); // no instruction
    const __m256d zero = _mm256_setzero_pd();   // vxorpd
    // vblendpd is 4-5 times faster than vinsertf128
    return _mm256_blend_pd( zero, low, 3 ); // vblendpd
}
// Load 2 doubles from memory, zero out other 2
inline __m256d load2( const double* source )
{
    return zeroupper( _mm_loadu_pd( source ) );
}
// Load 1 double from memory, zero out the other 3
inline __m256d load1( const double* source )
{
    return zeroupper( _mm_load_sd( source ) );
}
```

Comment: *vblendpd is 4-5 times faster than vinsertf128* uh, what?  On Zen 1, `vinsertf128` is actually faster.  On Intel, both are single uop but `vinsertf128` is a lane-crossing shuffle (3c latency, 1c throughput on HSW/SKL) while `vblendpd` is 1c latency, 0.333c throughput on Haswell/Skylake).  If you were trying to benchmark these *intrinsics*, then hopefully a good compiler would optimize away the `_mm256_blend_pd` entirely and just use `vmovupd xmm, [mem]` to zero-extend to 256 bits.  But some compilers (like MSVC and ICC) won't optimize away intrinsics.

Comment: In practice, clang optimizes away the blend-with-zero for the case where it's actually loading (not using a value that was already in a register).  But GCC9.2 doesn't.  https://godbolt.org/z/5ZXsR7.  Use `_mm256_set_pd(0,0,0, *source);` to get efficient asm from gcc and clang: just a `vmovsd` or `vmovq` load.  But MSVC still faceplants on that, using a stupid `vshufpd` + `vinsertf128` after a zero-extending load instruction.  https://godbolt.org/z/ww4uLL

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, just using `_mm256_set[r]_pd` already generates the most efficient code on clang/gcc, for all sizes from 1-3: https://godbolt.org/z/qEYrex